# How to serialize and deserialize User profile info in Datastore?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, serialization

For a User Entity, I want to create a property that is a dictionary of serialized data.  The data is:

```
time = time_value
name = name_value
id = id_value
```

Are there existing libraries to support serializing data, including DateTime values, and then deserializing them into their types (like DateTime, String, Integer) when fetching them from the Datastore?

Note: I'm going on the assumption that serializing the data is more efficient than encoding in JSON.  If that is a false assumption then this question is a moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in Python library `pickle` can be used to serialize and deserialize your data (while maintaining type information).  You can store the "pickled" data in a `db.BlobProperty`.

Unfortunately, Google App Engine's uses a Python-only implementation for the `pickle` library, and does not have support for the much faster `cPickle`.  Based on analysis presented by Konstantin in his article [Pickle vs JSON - Which is Faster?](http://kovshenin.com/archives/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/), it seems like you can expect to get better performance with JSON in this case.